# Sendmail sending all emails, but some are not arriving

Tags: email, postfix, sendmail

I have an application that sends out emails to various parties when an exception occurs. Every time I call sendmail to send out the emails, it is programmed to send somewhere between 1 and 12 emails. Most of the time when I send out these email blasts, 1 or 2 of the emails do not arrive in the appropriate inboxes. I've looked for some sort of pattern of which emails fail to arrive but it seems like it's completely random to me.

I've gone through and done some common sendmail troubleshooting fixes like properly configuring FQDN and getting a Public MX Record but it still seems to have an issue sending out every email consistently

Is there some sort of limit to the number of emails sendmail can handle at once? Or some kind of timeout that may be occurring?

Any suggestions or fixes would be much appreciated. Happy to try and supply more information.

Answer (score 0):

What does it say in `/var/log/maillog` for each missing email? That will at least let you know if the problem is on your end or outside your server.

Comment: Feb 19 11:13:28 digitalringfencing sm-mta[224067]: 11JG9B62224065: to=<me@email.com>, ctladdr=<foo@bar.net> (1000/1000), delay=00:04:17, xdelay=00:04:17, mailer=esmtp, pri=270812, relay=mx0a-001b2d01.pphosted.com. [148.163.156.1], dsn=2.0.0, stat=Sent (36tg04stdw-1 Message accepted for delivery)

Comment: The last part "stat=Sent (36tg04stdw-1 Message accepted for delivery)" is a successful message delivery. The mail server you contacted accepted the email and told your server there were no problems. Any missing emails after that point is on them not you. Maybe they are deciding to delete it on their end before giving it to the end user based on spam filters.

Comment: Ok thanks, that's good to know. Do you know of any way I can ensure they get pushed through on the email server end? Or is that completely based on their rules and there's not really anything I can do on my end?

Comment: Yes it is based on their rules, and the things they normally look for; Proper helo, matching PTR record, SPF record, dmarc record, dkim signing, valid return envelope.

Comment: Also depending on how much mail you sending, places like Yahoo have volume throttling where they only allow so many emails per time limit before they consider the mail spammy. I have no idea what they using now days but just to get you in the ballpark more than 100 emails per hour would trigger a deferral.